# I got another unknown hard drive called \\? \ Volume {1c8475c2-0000-0000-0000-100000000000} \. How do you know if it's a virus?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, performance

[these are system properties there is no hard disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN62A.png)

[and this is disk optimization and here it is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vE7H.png)

[screenshot of Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OwQe.png)

I searched the Internet for what this disk might be, but did not find it, you can help me with identifying it.
I was restoring the system, can it be an old image of the hard disk, or is it a virus!

Comment: This is just how partitions without drive letters look. Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: In Disk Management, right-click the drive, select Properties, Details tab, select Hardware IDs from the drop-down list and let us know the result. This will help identify the disk model.

Comment: I added a screenshot with the third photo